# How to add text to drawable in Android

Tags: android, drawing

I want to draw some text on image which is in Drawable folder. In my code I am getting drawable in the following way

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bubble);
```

Is there any way to add text through code that is programmatically to this drawable image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how flexible it is but it is possible to use a TextView and give it a background like so:

```
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My Text"
    android:background="@+drawable/image"
    />
```

or programmatically with [setBackgroundResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) or [setBackgroundDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)).

Edit:

With an xml layout file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="Hello!"
    android:background="@+drawable/image"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I get a result like this:

[image: Centered text in an image.]